# OpenCV template matching in multiple ROIs

Tags: c++, opencv, pattern-matching, marker, matchtemplate

I'm new to opencv so sorry if this question seems stupid.
I would like to find marker #1 for example in my image [detect marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOtLy.jpg). I have limited my search area to multiple ROIs (squares) then I cropped my image to the ROIs and transformed it using houghlines and warpaffine. For now only the first square is displayed. I would like to go through each ROI, match them with my template, skip bad matches and only return the best match (maybe with a percentage). Is this possible only using matchTemplate or is there maybe a better method to look for a specific marker after finding the squares in my image?

Comment: If you use matchTemplate you have to deal yourself with rotation and scale, but it seems a viable approach. Or you can have a look at [opencv - aruco](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d6d/tutorial_table_of_content_aruco.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Thx. Is there maybe a way to rotate my countours before cropping them?